# multiple exclude rules in powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a requirement to exclude files based on year, country name  and last modified date from that particular year and rest files from that particular year and the country moved to an archive folder

for an example

- SS_MM_Master_finland_2018.xlsx last modified date 27/06/2018 19:00.
- SS_MM_Master_finland_2017.xlsx last modified date 27/06/2017 19:00.

in this case, same country and year is different in the file name so that particular year- last modified date would be excluded so both the files will be excluded

wants to know if someone can give a small example based on their experience...not necessary to be from above example or  any multiple exclude rule or anything contribution would be appreciated

funny thing is that i have only single file excluder statement and do not know the multiple file excluder rule based on file name, Any example appericiated

I have only single file exclude statement

```
$sourcedir = 'C:\Test\Country'
$destdir = 'C:\Test\Country\Archive'

Get-ChildItem -File -Path $sourcedir |
    Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime -Descending |
    Select-Object -Skip 1 |
    Move-Item -Destination $destdir -force
```

thanks

Comment: Aside from changing itlay to finland your question isn't different or more clear than your last attempt. Exclude from what? There still isn't any code showing us where the file names come from or what you want to be excluded and how. Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve] by [edit]ing your question.

Comment: Show us where you are stuck. show us codes or errors. We are like a advanced debugger. You will need to do some of the work in order for this relationship to work

Comment: updated the main question sir

Comment: Both commentators are right that the question is like blind shooting and see what you can get in return.
So you can query with a Get-ChildItem of the folder and then remove all those that you don't need.
e.g.
`Get-ChildItem C:\Setup\Test\ | Export-csv c:\setup\test\export.csv -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter "|" -Encoding UTF8`
Then short that export or do whatever you want and import that csv as the filenames you want to move.

Comment: Are you saying you expect BOTH those files in your example to be excluded or not? I can't quite wrap my head around this bit `in this case, same country and year is different in the file name so that particular year- last modified date would be excluded so both the files will be excluded`.

Comment: yes to be excluded -Country  and based on year  max(last modified date)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I post this as an answer as I don't have the characters to do it as comment.
Let me see if I understand this.

```
$Files = Get-ChildItem -File C:\Setup | select Name, LastWriteTime
```

You then have an export of the files like:

```
Name                           LastWriteTime       
----                           -------------       
SS_MM_Master_Finland_2017.txt  6/27/2018 4:30:09 PM
SS_MM_Master_Finland_2018.txt  6/27/2018 4:30:09 PM
SS_MM_Master_Germany_2017.txt  6/27/2018 4:30:09 PM
SS_MM_Master_Germany_2018y.txt 6/27/2018 4:30:09 PM
SS_MM_Master_Italy_2017.txt    6/27/2018 4:30:09 PM
SS_MM_Master_Italy_2018.txt    6/27/2018 4:30:09 PM
```

And then you can go with an foreach with if like:

```
foreach ($File in $Files) {

If ($File.Name -like "*Italy*" -and $File.Name -like "*2017*") {
Write-Host $File.Name
}
Else{
Write-Host "This is not the file you are looking for" $file.Name
}
}
```

I believe you can understand the concept behind this code. You can replace the *Italy* with a variable that you can do with Read-Host that goes for all your conditions on the if statement and then if those are true move the file to the other folder.

Hope this answer will help you.