# Split File name for max( Modified date)

Tags: powershell, powershell-v6.0

I have a requirement to exclude files based on year, country name and last modified date from that particular year and rest files from that particular year and the country moved to an archive folder

for an example

```
SS_MM_Master_finland_2018.xlsx last modified date 27/06/2018 19:00.

SS_MM_Master_finland_2017.xlsx last modified date 27/06/2017 19:00.
```

in this case, same country and year is different in the file name so that particular year- last modified date would be excluded so both the files will be excluded

wants to know if someone can give a small example based on their experience...not necessary to be from above example or any multiple exclude rule or anything contribution would be appreciated

I have tried

```
$Files = Get-ChildItem -File C:\Setup | select Name, LastWriteTime
foreach($FileName in $Files)
{
    ##### - Split elements: 0 = SS, 1 = MM, 2 = Master, 3 = Country, 4 = Year
    $MyFile = $FileName # Get FileName
    $fileCountry = $FileName.Name[0].Split('_')[3] # Get Country
    $fileYear = $FileName.Name[0].Split('_')[4] # Get Year
}
```

how to get max (last modified date) based on the country and year

I tried below mentioned query today and getting all the values year , country but how to get max(last modified date for that particular year and country

```
$Files = Get-ChildItem -File C:\Users\rramesnc\Documents\Advisory_Rate | select Name, LastWriteTime
foreach($FileName in $Files)
{

####- Split elements: 0 = SS, 1 = MM, 2 = Master, 3 = Country, 4 = Year
#### - Get FileName:
$MyFile = $FileName

#### - Get Country:

$FileName -split "-"

#### - Get Year

$fileYear = $FileName.Name.Split("_")[4,3]

$fileCountry.Name

#### - Sample getting the year value from the ".LastWriteTime":

$FileName

$fileYear

$FileName.LastWriteTime
```

Comment: Which version of powershell are you actually on?

Comment: Are you working with several user accounts or is this a homework? See this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51064464/multiple-exclude-rules-in-powershell)

Comment: powershell version 6.3..I understand my friend is also posting question but my logic is modified one ...some related example will also fine with above query

Comment: Your description is as worse as your friends (or your teachers?) How can 2 samples be sufficient to exclude on several parameters. I simply don't understand what you (all) are after. In general you can Select-Object/Where-Object/Sort-Object/Group-Object with a calculated Property which splits the relevant parts from the filename. To get the last split in an unknown count you can use negative indices [-1] for the last etc.

Comment: There isn't a version 6.3.  Even the latest release is only 6.1

Comment: As a shorter way to retrieve information: `$country, $year = $FileName.Name.Split('_')[3,4]`

Comment: one logic is that ...i am able to find last modified date but based on filename +year and max last modified date is only task... and version is  6.3.9600

Comment: Hi TheIncorrigible1 ...agreed...getting split values but based on that max(modfied date ) for that year...is difficult

Comment: Hi Expert, i am able to get year and other split name in modified code attached in main question ...how can i get max last modified date in to it

Comment: suggesion please